# Problem with mhchem subscript and superscript alignement

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, mhchem

In the `mhchem` package, there is an example of writing CrO42- with the command `\ce{CrO4^2-}` which produce a formula where the 2- is not aligned with the 4, which is exactly what I want to reproduce.
However, when I try on my computer, in a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{CrO4^2-}
\end{document}
```

The subscript 4 et superscript 2- are aligned ...

Do someone know where it comes from and how to deal that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :) Running your example I get a staggered arrangement of subscript and charge. This is a relatively new behaviour for `mhchem`. Which version do you have? The current version is v3.17 (2014/03/27). BTW: [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) also has staggered arrangement which can be customized using options.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! I think I have the 2011/04/29 v3.10. I'll try to update to the 3.17.

Comment: I updated to the 3.17. I have now an error message : \str_case:nnn not yet defined. I suppose this is something linked with using latex3 instead of latex2

Comment: Search this site how to update your TeX distribution. Updating packages manually is tricky as they depend on other packages. Usually TeX distributions like MiKTeX and TeX Live have package managers...

Comment: Yes generally I use these managers. But I'm at work and there are network protections which prevent update ...

Comment: Problem solved with an update at home. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by the OP in the comments.